# Chrome issue about popup print preview window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. In parent window, click one button the bring up another window (child).
2. Call javascript window.print() in child window, print preview window popup
3. Neither click the print button nor the cancel button in print preview, close the child window directly
4. Now back to parent window and the input box becomes "disabled" and not able to input anything

Is this a bug in Chrome and is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Now I have an alternative way to bypass the issue, that is to use iframe within the parent window to trigger the print script, in this case, can only close the print preview window by clicking the cancel button if don't want to print. This approach works perfectly for me.